# Why is this working on Python IDE without user input but not in Pycharm with user input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When i give a value to "a and b" and ask for "a+b" ir runs fine but when i ask for input it doesn't, it says "TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str".

a = input()

b = input()

x = a + b

print ("Z = %d" % (x))

Thanks!

Comment: Damn, it is Python GUI not Python IDE :(

Comment: you can edit your question by clicking on the edit button below the question. And isn't user input a string? If so i think you need to convert it to a number before you use it. (just a random thought)

Answer (score 2):

The format() function returns a string, you can convert it to a number with int()

Comment: How? I would type input(int())?

Comment: Other way around, `int(input())` ;)

Comment: Ohh forget it, i tried int(input()) and it worked, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

change `print ("Z = %d" % (x))` to `print ("Z = %s" % (x))`

`'s'` converts an object to a String